# How to retrieve data of specific users from firebase into a listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code of how currently/specific logged in users can add to the database, I need help in retrieving the information of these specific user in a listview or recyclerView. I don't want another user to get the data of a different user.

This is also the structure of my database, within the users water bill payment details, the first node generated is the Users ID and also the next node after the Users Id is the transaction id.

Database structure:
[image: Structure of my database]

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
databaseWater= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users water bill payment details").child(currentID);

progressBar= new ProgressDialog(this);
moneynumberwat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moneynumberwat);
moneypinwat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moneypinwat);
meterwat = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.meterwat);
user_idwat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_idwat);
amountwat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountwat);
modePaywat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modePaywat);
Paywater = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Paywater);

Paywater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        addPayWaterInfo();
    }
});

setubk();
setupbk();
}


private void setubk() {
    ImageButton btn2 = findViewById(R.id.bord);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(PayOffWater.this, Interface.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void setupbk() {
    ImageButton btn2 = findViewById(R.id.bak);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(PayOffWater.this, Services.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void addPayWaterInfo() {
    String moneynumw = moneynumberwat.getText().toString();
    String pincodelitw = moneypinwat.getText().toString();
    String meterw = meterwat.getText().toString();
    String customerw = user_idwat.getText().toString();
    String cashw = amountwat.getText().toString();
    String mpayw = modePaywat.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if( moneynumw.isEmpty()||moneynumw.length()>10 || moneynumw.length()<10 ||
                pincodelitw.length()>4 || pincodelitw.length()<4 ||meterw.isEmpty()||cashw.isEmpty()|| mpayw.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"provide correct information before payment can be successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else{
            String id = databaseWater.push().getKey();
            com.example.iamstix_jnr.utility.PayOf.Pay pay = new Pay(moneynumw,pincodelitw,meterw,customerw,cashw,mpayw);
            databaseWater.child(id).setValue(pay);

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(PayOffWater.this,Success.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact question/problem? Do you have a problem with showing the information on the screen or maybe with restricting access to the data?

Comment: my extact question is how to retrieve data to specific users in a listview

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate to the last id.

```
    databaseWater= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users water bill payment details").child(currentID).child("id of no 3.");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an `ChildEventListener` on your database reference and on each callback add or remove or update the adapter that you have on your recyclerview

```
databaseWater.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            //todo add to adapter
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            //todo update adapter
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //todo remove from adapter
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            //todo update adapter

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```